# can i make an internal frame disappear when application ran in netbeans? (java)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I wanted to make a menu internal frame in NetBeans that would be activated using a button. But I cannot make it disappear when the application loaded. I tried this:

```java
jInternalFrame1.setVisible(false);
```

But this didn't work. Is there a way to make it disappear and only open when clicked the button?

Comment: It should work.  Consider editing your question and adding a [mre] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I cannot find anything I could add. Also, setVisible doesn't work on it because all of the NetBeans JFrame designer.